# htaccess redirect with wildcard when switching CMS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Switching from ExpressionEngine to Wordpress and need to set up redirects in htaccess.

The paths to the articles will change from mysite.com/section/read/article-name
to mysite.com/article-name/. The section part of the path has six variants.

Unsure whether to look at redirectmatch or rewrite rule being a toatl novice with htaccess.

Thanks

Comment: Which path is which? `/section/read/article-name` is from ExpressionEngine and `/article-name` is Wordpress, or is it the other way round?

Comment: The first is from ExpressionEngine

Answer (score 0):

Either would work, so I'll use `RedirectMatch`. To be specific about the section name, it would be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/(?:section|another-section|third-section)/read/(.+)$" /$1
```

Replacing your section names in there, separated by pipes.

Or for anything in a directory called read in a top level directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/[^/]+/read/(.+)$" /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a one to one mapping and just the final part to be preserved, you don't need `RedirectMatch`. [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is sufficient

```
Redirect /section/read /
```

When it works as expected, you may set the status code to `301`.

```
Redirect 301 /section/read /
```

---

If you want to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) instead, this would be

```
RewriteRule ^section/read/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Thanks for that Olaf

Comment: Just to let you know Olaf that the simplest of the suggestions, ie your Redirect was the one that worked best, thanks